# AngularJs is preventing link to be clicked twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS not to build SPA but just for certain features in the system. I'm having a trouble to find out why Angular is preventing page from being refreshed after it get's there or how to disable/workaround it.

So I have simple menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/admin">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/profile">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
```

And when I'm already on the `http://example.com/admin` page and I'm clicking in first link (`/admin`) then nothing happens.

I could detect if a certain `a` element has a `href` and then use `window.location` but unfortunately I'm using AJAX in some other parts of the system so that won't fit.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you certain this is angular? If you remove angular.js does it still fail to go to `/admin`?

Comment: Yes I'm certain, if I remove `ng-app="app"` then it's working properly again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working with a Single Page Application. The router takes care of navigating between different application routes, but the browser never fetches an entirely new page.

When you click on a link for a page that you're already on, there is no where to navigate to.

**EDIT:** You could write a directive that will detect clicks on anchor tags, and if the route is the same, it could trigger a page refresh. That will give you the behaviour you're looking for. However, I struggle to where this would be desirable.

**EDIT 2**: This is what stops your navigation: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.x/src/ng/location.js#L889.

As far as I can see, there is nothing you can do to disable that behaviour, or if there is, it will be an uglier and more fragile solution that creating your own directive that will trigger a page refresh.

Comment: Thing is I'm not :) as I already wrote it - I just have system that and I want to use angular for certain features - for example build-in floating Q&A tool. So yes, there is a place where to navigate.

Comment: Yeah, I think that could be an option but I would rather first try to disable this behavior from Angular side rather than write such a directive as this can be a problem in future.

Comment: Are you using `$route` (ngRoute)?

Comment: No, I do not use `ngRoute` - I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be using `ng-href` and http://plnkr.co/edit/stdkjN?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, maybe, however I doubt. I'm not really able to rewrite whole system in order to user AngularJS as a library for certain parts.